# IBM DB2 SQL1730N when trying to move database from one machine to another via backup/restore

Tags: encryption, db2, database-backups, db2-luw

I've been trying to implement the DB2 mechanism for restoring backups from one machine onto another, as part of our disaster recovery mechanism and for some kinds of problem diagnosis. I am making a copy of the keystore files and copying them back into DB2 before restoring, so everything should be OK.

And in most scenarios I've tested, it *is* OK.

However, if the machine I'm restoring onto has been used before (eg for other testing), then trying to restore one of the databases is failing oddly. For example, I'm trying to restore a backup from 11/26 onto another machine which was last used on 11/28, and DB2 is saying:

SQL1730N  The command or operation failed because the master key label does not exist in the keystore file. Label being used: "DB2_SYSGEN_db2inst1_MYDATABASENAME_2017-11-28-20.58.07". File type number: "DB  CFG". File name: "SQLDBCONF".

Note that the datestamp in that label is later than the backup I'm restoring, so the complaint makes some sense ... except that I don't understand where that master key label actually is, why it's persisting, and why copying in the keystore files before doing the restore wasn't sufficient to prevent it.

IBM does have some documentation on this error, at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01730n.html and https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/319149/how-to-change-the-master-key-password-after-restor.html ... but I'm not really a DB2 user and I'm having trouble figuring out what they're suggesting I change.

Can someone sketch a sequence of operations which will make a backdated backup from one machine reliably load onto another? I'm sure there is a Best Practice for DB2 backup and restore out there somewhere which would address this, but I've been hunting entirely too long and not finding it... and I can't believe I'm the only one who finds DB2's backup/restore system confusing.

I'm using DB2 10.5, if that helps at all.

Comment: This does not seem directly related to backup/restore, but to key management and how that works. Are all your backups encrypted using the native encryption? Are you following this procedure? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0070021.html

Comment: This is an indication that the master key embedded in the backup image may not be present in the keystore on the target. Did you check the master key labels?